# image size compressing. Can't make imageView look like photoshop image

Tags: android-layout

I've got a tablet Galaxy tab gt-p5110 and I'm trying to adopt photoshop design. This tablet has a 1280 x 800 resolution and my photoshop design has the same resolution as well. However, when I transfer images photoshop on Android layout everything seems to be compressed and smaller. It simply doesn't actually look like in photoshop design.

What am I missing here ? Resolution is the same.

Answer (score 0):

Mabye you have different color profiles in use?